# Using beautifulsoup to get the text.

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am running into problems using beautifulsoup to strip the html out and only have the text. When I run it I get the error `AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get_text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?` Is there anyway to just get the text when I `findAll` in my `divs` variable like I have it?

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.brightscope.com/form-5500/basic-info/107299/Orthopedic-Institute-Of-Pennsylvania/15801790/Orthopedic-Institute-Of-Pennsylvania-401k-Profit-Sharing-Plan/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.findAll('span', class_='float-right').get_text()

for each in divs:
    print(each)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.brightscope.com/form-5500/basic-info/107299/Orthopedic-Institute-Of-Pennsylvania/15801790/Orthopedic-Institute-Of-Pennsylvania-401k-Profit-Sharing-Plan/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.findAll('span', class_='float-right') #not on the collection of elements

for each in divs:
    print(each.get_text()) #get_text goes here on the element
```

EDIT:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.brightscope.com/form-5500/basic-info/107299/Orthopedic-Institute-Of-Pennsylvania/15801790/Orthopedic-Institute-Of-Pennsylvania-401k-Profit-Sharing-Plan/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
divs = [e.get_text() for e in soup.findAll('span', class_='float-right')]
```

Will get you a list of divs in string format

Comment: I want to take the html out because I want to eventually index the list to find “Audited”. So should I set another list and append just the text to the new list?

Comment: You can use a list comprehension as shown in the edit